# Splash screen for iOS PWA

Tags: ios, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, splash-screen

Is there a way to configure only one splash screen for PWA(developed using react) for all devices in iOS,
Currently I'm setting image for each device with media query
eg:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="screen and (device-width: 768px) 
and (device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape)"
      href="/images/splash-screens/iPhone_12.png"/>
```

This process seems to be tedious to do it for every device and maintain many images for each device in landscape and portrait.

Please suggest any possible way to tackle this?